# Restler 3 post call param with one value or another

Tags: api, post, parameter-passing, restler

I'm using Reslter 3 and I have a post call with parameter(and the class) implemented. All fields are required. I want to extend it to work again with one param but from one class or a different one. Is it possible?
The current implementation is :

```
* @param Class_A $data
```

and I want it to work something like this:

```
* @param Class_A $data || Class_B $data
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax

```
@param Class_A|Class_B $data
```

Read [PHPDoc Reference](http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html) for more info